# How to push OpenFaaS image to Minishift/Openshift Docker registry?

Tags: docker, openshift, minishift, faas

I'm trying to deploy a locally written OpenFaaS function to Minishift. My YAML file is:

```
provider:
  name: faas
  gateway: http://gateway-openfaas.10.10.80.33.nip.io

functions:
  test:
  lang: python
  handler: ./test
  image: 172.30.1.1:5000/test
```

172.30.1.1:5000 is the result of calling

```
minishift openshift registry
```

When I access the OpenFaaS UI through the Openshift Console, I can deploy functions properly from there. I can also see the function I tried to deploy locally there, but the Docker image is not in the Minishift Docker registry. To push my image there, I'm trying to use the command:

```
faas-cli push -f ./test.yml
```

Unfortunately, I receive the following error:

```
PS D:\projects> faas-cli push -f ./test.yml
[0] > Pushing test.
The push refers to a repository [172.30.1.1:5000/test]
8124325a272a: Preparing
2fbb584cb870: Preparing
e6dd715c8997: Preparing
ac20ff3419a9: Preparing
18adf8f88cf9: Preparing
ab495c1b9bd4: Waiting
09c56bd3ad6c: Waiting
a291b1700920: Waiting
8a65d1376e5b: Waiting
155a0aa5c33a: Waiting
8984417f4638: Waiting
a7d53ea16e81: Waiting
e53f74215d12: Waiting
unauthorized: repository name "test" invalid: it must be of the format 
<project>/<name>
2018/03/22 11:30:53 ERROR - Could not execute command: [docker push 
172.30.1.1:5000/test]
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Looks like](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/install_config/install/docker_registry.html#access) you need a project name before your image name, like `openshift` in the following example

```
$ docker push 172.30.124.220:5000/openshift/busybox
...
cf2616975b4a: Image successfully pushed
Digest: sha256:3662dd821983bc4326bee12caec61367e7fb6f6a3ee547cbaff98f77403cab55
```

Try changing the image section in your test.yml to be `172.30.1.1:5000/openfaas/test` or similar.

You may also need to get an access token and use it with `docker login`, as described in the above link, if you have not already done so:

```
$ oc whoami -t
$ docker login -u <username> -e <any_email_address> -p <token_value> <registry_service_host:port>
```

Comment: Adding the project name to the path in the YAML file was the correct solution. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

@codemonkey is right. One need to include project name as part of any application image.

Also, I would suggest you to try $(minishift openshift registry) since if you give you registry IP:Port.

See more detail See more https://docs.openshift.org/latest/minishift/openshift/openshift-docker-registry.html.